# Which is more secure using Java Mail

Tags: android, security, authentication, smtp, jakarta-mail

I've code to send emails using JavaMail and am keen to understand which of the two options below is more secure and better practice. Both sets of code currently work sending via SMTP using Gmail, Outlook or Yahoo. The code is from Android, but is more generalist Java.

```
String password = "**********";
String username = "????@gmail.com";//"????@outlook.com";//"????@yahoo.com";
String smtp_host_setting = "smtp.gmail.com";//"smtp-mail.outlook.com";//"smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
String smtp_port_setting = "587";//"587";//"587";
String recipient_email_address = "recipient@recipient_server.com";
String email_subject = "Email Subject";
String email_msg = "Some text for the message\r\nThanks!";
Session session = null;
```

This approach uses getPasswordAuthentication() :

```
/************************ OPTION 1 *****************************/
private int send_email_temp(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp_host_setting); // YAHOO needs it to be mail.smtp.host, GMAIL and OUTLOOK were OK with mail.host (and with this)
    //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtp_port_setting);

    session = Session.getInstance(
            props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    ActuallySendAsync_temp asy = new ActuallySendAsync_temp(true);
    asy.execute();

    return 0;
}


class ActuallySendAsync_temp extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    public ActuallySendAsync_temp(boolean boo) {
        // something to do before sending email
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipient_email_address));
            message.setSubject(email_subject);
            message.setText(email_msg);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // something to do after sending email
    }
}
/************************ OPTION 1 - End ***********************/
```

This approach uses session.getTransport("smtp") and .connect for authentication :

```
/************************ OPTION 2 *****************************/
private int send_email_temp(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp_host_setting); // YAHOO needs it to be mail.smtp.host, GMAIL and OUTLOOK were OK with mail.host (and with this)
    //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtp_port_setting);

    session = Session.getInstance(props);

 ActuallySendAsync_temp asy = new ActuallySendAsync_temp(true);
    asy.execute();

    return 0;
}


class ActuallySendAsync_temp extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    public ActuallySendAsync_temp(boolean boo) {
        // something to do before sending email
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipient_email_address));
            message.setSubject(email_subject);
            message.setText(email_msg);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(smtp_host_setting, username, password);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // something to do after sending email
    }
}
/************************ OPTION 2 - End ***********************/
```

Are the two approaches equivalent, or is one option considered more secure than the other?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're equivalently secure.  One is just more verbose.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill for your answer. Can you suggest a more secure way using JavaMail?

Comment: A more secure way to do what, exactly?  Managing passwords in an application is always tricky, whether they're used to authenticate to a mail server or something else.  You might want to look into [OAuth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2), which avoids some of the problems but is significantly more complicated.

Comment: I agreed about the challenges of managing passwords in applications, but I'm happy with how I am handling that side of it. I wanted to check that the approach I am using above is the most secure way to use JavaMail authentication direct via password. Are you happy with the approach I have adopted in this area? For example does one approach leave the garbage collector to remove the password from RAM which would perhaps be be a sloppy approach?

Comment: JavaMail manages the passwords as Strings instead of char arrays so you'll have the GC issue.  There's no other options, sorry.